# fadeOut not working in IE7/IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm not quite sure why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/comatoseduck/xMSwQ/) bit of jQuery isn't working in IE7 & IE8.  Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I just needed to remove position:relative and it fades out perfectly.  I'm not quite sure why that is though...

Answer (score 2):

Well for one thing since you are using jQuery do this without the inline js:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var checkbox = this;
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        $("#message1").stop(true, true).show().fadeOut(10000);
        $("#message2").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#message1").stop(true, true).hide();
        $("#message2").stop(true, true).show().fadeOut(10000);
    }
});
```

Just doing this might fix the IE problem

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/xMSwQ/5/