# Fadeout not working in IE7/IE8 (have tried previously suggested fixes)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, fadeout

After reading previous answers I tried removing `position:fixed`, setting the opacity to 100 before fadeout, and adding `display: inline-block` but nothing has worked so far.

Here is the site: http://www.theseamstressofbloomsbury.co.uk/lookbook/

The element to be faded out has the following CSS:

`#loading-wrapper {
  background: url(images/background.jpg) center top #eee9d1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align:center;
  color:#866a4b;
}`

And jQuery:

`$('#loading-wrapper').fadeOut('slow');`

Related questions I looked into:

- [fadeOut not working in IE7/IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023909/fadeout-not-working-in-ie7-ie8)
- [jquery IE Fadein and Fadeout Opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284163/jquery-ie-fadein-and-fadeout-opacity)
- [Does jQuery's fadeIn() and fadeOut() not work with IE 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114516/does-jquerys-fadein-and-fadeout-not-work-with-ie-8)

Any other tips?

Cheers!

Comment: Does it work here for you? http://jsfiddle.net/xpbf4/show/ seems to work for me.

Comment: You know that it's not really inside a document ready handler, it's called from yepnope directly on pageload.

Comment: Also, you have errors, the console throws "Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: li:nth-child"

Comment: No Kevin, your fiddle doesn't work for me either. adeneo, I realise about the handler but for some reason when I place the fadeout under window load it never fades out, and document ready is too fast!